# What is the name of this takedown / throw?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, judo, wrestling, throwing, identification

Today, whilst sparring with my opponent I was trying to pull of a lot of kneeling shoulder throws, but my opponent simply walked over me several times. I came back up from one attempt and managed to sway the opponent so that all of the opponents bodyweight was on their right leg. I grasped into that leg with my right hand and rolled right while rotating the opponent from the collar grip that I had retained with my left hand and the leg so that I landed in a side position with my knee over their chest, and received some minor applause.

Does it resemble any specific throw? I know that some like to shoot for the legs and roll / push / rotate in some direction in order to get a dominant position early in the match, but those usually result in slow rolls. The one I managed to pull off had actual power and timing in it.

Comment: This textual description is very confusing. What direction are you facing relative to your opponent (this defines rolling left/right)? Facing opponent, back to opponent, 90 degrees with opponent on your left/right? Where is your left hand? Where is your right hand? How are you grasping the leg? What does it mean that you "grasped into"?

Comment: Facing, yes. I'll add those details. I had them at one draft but somehow they slipped out :)

Comment: As for grasping: wrapping something with fingers? Best grip you can get from the ankle and so on.

Comment: What direction does the opponent fall? Forward or backward or to their left or right?

Comment: The description kind of reminds me of kata guruma...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD09HBiPgEU

Comment: To the right. So not kata guruma. It's more of a sacrifice throw than anything else.

Comment: And to be clear; I never lifted the opponent on my shoulders like in kata guruma. Picture putting someone on one leg, and take that leg of the ground by pulling it to the left side (assuming left hand on collar and right on leg). The collar grip was used for guiding the opponent on the way down, and keeping control afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

### Judo *Kibisu gaeshi*

The major point in descriptions of [*kibisu gaeshi*](https://youtu.be/q0N-vvgrg-w) is grabbing and reaping of the heel with a hand. The suggested applications of *Kibisu gaeshi* include continuations both from a *seoi nage* feint as well as a when your opponent dodges *seoi nage* by circling towards your front. It also used to be a common continuation from *uchi mata*, when the opponent is standing on one leg to avoid the leg reap.

Unlike the classification for leg techniques, *kibisu gaeshi* may be performed from either the inside or outside of the opponent's leg.

Unlike the discussions of *kata guruma*, classification does not seem to depend on whether you sacrifice your standing position for this throw.

### Wrestling ankle pick

Wrestling usually sets up the [ankle pick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWnUqflawgI) using downward force on the opponent's neck with the collar tie to break their balance, but it is a very similar technique.

Comment: Interesting. The seoinage part (the video) was kinda how it happened, but I did go for the other leg. The follow up from the kouchi gari a bit later has similar "punch" to it. I guess the direction doesn't really matter?

Comment: @user8472 As far as I know, direction does not matter for classification. I would think it's easiest to go to uke's rear, side of the leg being reaped, or the corner in between.

Answer (score 3):

### Wrestling firemans carry

It sounds like you are talking about some variation of the wrestling [fireman's carry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kth0Uqo5ygY). I am not sure whether actually picking the opponent up in wrestling changes the classification. The instructor in this video definitely lifts completely in one example, but in another appears to proceed directly to the sacrifice.

### Judo uki waza or yoko otoshi (formal), kata guruma (informal)

In judo, this has been called [kata guruma](https://youtu.be/IOYFMQbnzUE?t=1m25s), though if you are using a sacrifice technique, this is not the current formal classification. For understanding arcane formal judo classification, the best source is *Kodokan Judo: Throwing Techniques* by Toshiro Daigo, Kodansha, Tokyo, Japan 2005. Toshiro Daigo, the current head of the Kodokan, explains a sacrifice in the kata guruma position would be either uki waza or yoko otoshi.

Daigo p. 232 discusses "uki-waza from the form of kata guruma":

> After a study by the Kodokan Waza Research Institute (April 1, 1997), it was decided that this technique is related to uki-waza and not kata-guruma, because the concept of the throw is based on the principle of yoko-sutemi-waza [side sacrifice technique].

Daigo p. 235:

> It is extremely difficult to clarify the differences between these techniques [yoko otoshi and uki waza], and is a matter for the judges.

The points of judo throw classification can be quite complicated and opaque. I would recommend against investing too deeply in understanding the Kodokan current thinking about the differences between uki waza and yoko otoshi. In everyday usage, I would also expect to see this called kata guruma as it is in the linked youtube video, as the official word on this is only from 1997.

Comment: It's not firemans carry or uki waza. My leg grib was from the ankle and the throw itself had nothing to do with my shoulders. Yoko otoshi kinda comes close, but instead of tripping the leg with my leg, I used my hand to lift the leg off the ground.

Comment: What comes to Kodokan and Judo techniques in general; Judo died for me when they banned all leg grabs, so minor details of a throw classification don't really interest me. I just want to get better as a grappler in general.

Comment: Yoko otoshi does not require blocking the leg. The major point is to off-balance the opponent and throw to the side while falling. Blocking the leg is optional; I often find that falling too close to the opponent is ineffective while falling further away is harder to resist.